# strcpy() creates error

Tags: c, initialization, runtime-error, strcpy, strncpy

I have this structure which i am trying to initialize using the following code. It gets run time error when trying to initialize "finger_print"

What is wrong with it?

```
typedef struct fpinfo
{
    unsigned long chunk_offset;
    unsigned long chunk_length;
    unsigned char fing_print[33];

}fpinfo;
```

the function:

```
struct fpinfo* InitHTable(struct fpinfo ht[][B_ENTRIES])
{
    unsigned char garb[33]={0};

        for (int j = 0; j < BUCKETS; ++j) 
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < B_ENTRIES; ++k)
            {
                ht[j][k].chunk_offset=0;
                ht[j][k].chunk_length=0;
                strcpy((char*)ht[j][k].fing_print[32],(const char*)garb);
                //ht[j][k].fing_print[32]=0;
            }
        }
        curr_tanker=1;
        return &ht[0][0];
}
```

It is the same with strncpy()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
strcpy((char*)ht[j][k].fing_print[32],(const char*)garb);
```

You're treating the last character of `fing_print` as a pointer and attempting to write to it. Perhaps you meant:

```
strcpy((char*)ht[j][k].fing_print,(const char*)garb);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [strncpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strncpy/) if you want to specify number of characters that should be copied. Replace these lines:

```
strcpy((char*)ht[j][k].fing_print[32],(const char*)garb);
//ht[j][k].fing_print[32]=0;
```

with these:

```
strncpy((char*)ht[j][k].fing_print, (const char*)garb, 32);
ht[j][k].fing_print[32] = '\0';
```

Comment: Better yet `#define SIZE 33` and `SIZE-1`

Comment: @zmccord: Agree. Although functionality of `strcpy` function is what this question is about.

Comment: @zmccord: Also `#define SIZE 32` and `SIZE+1` in declaration is much more intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

The statement `strcpy((char*)ht[j][k].fing_print[32],(const char*)garb);` doesn't make sense. It takes element 32 of the `fing_print` array, interprets that as an address, and tries to write the contents of `garb` to that address (which should have no side effect at all, because `garb` only contains zeros, and is regarded as a 0-length string by `strcpy()`).

If you want to set `ht[j][k].fing_print` to all zeros, use `memset(ht[j][k].fing_print, 0, sizeof(ht[j][k].fing_print))`.